# How to delete a sprite at collision in a TDS game pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I simply just want to delete the zombie sprite from my sprite group when the bullet collides with the zombie to create the sense the zombie is dying.
I already tried the `Zombie(1,1).kill()` but it did not work unfortunatley.
here is my code if it will be helpful...

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
from random import randint
import math
from pygame.math import Vector2
from pygame.constants import K_LSHIFT, K_SPACE, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, MOUSEBUTTONUP, K_e
pygame.init()
import time
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)




class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x , y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphics/Robot 1/robot1_gun.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.orig_image = pygame.image.load('graphics/Robot 1/robot1_gun.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rotate_vel = 1
        self.cross_image = pygame.image.load('graphics/crosshair049.png')
        

    def draw(self, surface):
        """ Draw on surface """
        # blit yourself at your current position
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        dir_vec = pygame.math.Vector2()
        dir_vec.from_polar((180, -self.rotate_vel))
        cross_pos = dir_vec + self.rect.center
        cross_x, cross_y = round(cross_pos.x), round(cross_pos.y)
        surface.blit(self.cross_image,  self.cross_image.get_rect(center = (cross_x, cross_y)))
        

    def movement(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        dist = 3 # distance moved in 1 frame, try changing it to 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] or key[pygame.K_s]: # down key
            self.y += dist # move down
        elif key[pygame.K_UP] or key[pygame.K_w]: # up key
            self.y -= dist # move up
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] or key[pygame.K_d]: # right key
            self.x += dist # move right
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT] or key[pygame.K_a]: # left key
            self.x -= dist # move left


    def rotate(self, surface):

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_LSHIFT]:
            self.rotate_vel += 5
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.orig_image, self.rotate_vel)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
            surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        if keys[K_SPACE]:
            self.rotate_vel += -5
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.orig_image, self.rotate_vel)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
            surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)


    def update(self):
        self.movement()
        self.draw(screen)
        self.rotate(screen)



class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, angle):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphics/weapons/bullets/default_bullet.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
        self.speed = 25
        self.pos = pos
        self.dir_vec = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.dir_vec.from_polar((self.speed, -angle))


    def update(self, screen):
        self.pos += self.dir_vec
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)



class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x , y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphics/zombie/zoimbie1_hold.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x,y))
        self.orig_image = pygame.image.load('graphics/Robot 1/robot1_gun.png').convert_alpha()

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.draw(screen)



#screen
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

#player
player_sprite = Player(600, 300)
player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
player.add(player_sprite)

#bullet
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()


#Zombie
zombie_sprite = Zombie(600, 300)
zombie = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombie.add(zombie_sprite)
#keys
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                    pos = player_sprite.rect.center
                    new_bullet = Bullet(pos, player_sprite.rotate_vel)
                    bullet_group.add(new_bullet)

                   
                    


    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(zombie_sprite,bullet_group , True):
                Zombie(1,1).kill()
                

    bullet_group.update(screen)
    #screen
    screen.fill('grey')
    #player sprite funtions
    player.update() 
    #buller group draw
    bullet_group.draw(screen)
    bullet_group.update(screen) 
    #Zombie update
    zombie.update()  

    clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `zombie_sprite.kill()` instead of `Zombie(1,1).kill()`

You are instantiating a new object instead of destroying the original one.